# Get user role after authorization

Tags: angular, spring-security-oauth2, angular9

I want to implement Spring Boot Project with Angular 9 based on OAuth2 for security. The problem which is not clear for me is what is the best way to get the user role after user authentication. I found 2 ways:

1. Add properly after user is authenticated using OAuth2 into the response payload:

   ```
   {
    "access_token": "wdwdw",
      "token_type": "bearer",
      "refresh_token": "wdwdwdwd",
      "expires_in": 4,
      "scope": "read",
      "role": [
        "ROLE_ADMIN"
      ],
      "jti": "wfwfe"
    }
   ```
2. The second way is to use a second API call to `oauth/check_token` in order to get the role:

$ curl localhost:8080/oauth/check_token/?token=fc9e4ad4-d6e8-4f57-b67e-c0285dcdeb58

```
{
  "scope": [
    "read",
    "write"
  ],
  "active": true,
  "exp": 1544940147,
  "authorities": [
    "ROLE_USER"
  ],
  "client_id": "ger-client-id"
}
```

I'm interested which of both ways is better in terms of security and best practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll go for the first way in case you me need to control the routing and modules loading based on user authorities so you don't need to fire a new request for just find authorities.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. There is one more case which needs to be covered. I want when I change user profile role into DB to apply this change also on the Angular side. Looks like for every request I need to get the user role in order to be able to change it dynamically. How did you implement such a case?

Comment: in this case you may invalidate access token by add it to black list to enforce user to log in  again

Answer (score 0):

I'll prefer the first way whatever the security credentials will pass as object properties and you can use it.